# Unable to upload files with larger than 100kb using Creative Exchange/CLI

Tags: sxa, sxa-cli

I have created a new [theme using the CLI](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-a-theme-using-sxa-cli.html) and have it connected to my local instance of Sitecore. This all mostly works without any issues. I have my settings to upload source files (SASS, CSS and JS). However, when certain edits are made to the files, it fails to upload those files into Sitecore.

The instance is connected without any errors, since smaller files are uploaded to into the Media Library without any issue, but it seems that any file larger than 100kb or so fails with this following error:

[image: Upload error]

Http Status code 413 is [Payload Too Large](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413). Which suggests there is a setting somewhere that prevents anything over 100kb. The error is the same for SASS, CSS, JavaScript or image files.

Anyone come across this issue before or know how to fix it?

I'm using Sitecore + SXA 9.3.

Comment: Could this be related to the uploadreadaheadsize setting. Might be set to some value close to 100 KB.

Comment: Does the component-accordion.css fail in everytime or in some cases ?

Comment: @AbhayDhar Yes, it fails every time, and always for any file over a certain size (css, scss, js, images). This set up is using Docker, not sure if that should make a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked this on my local instance and I've no problems with uploading files larger than 100kb. I do not recall any limits. What is more, our optimize-min files are always bigger than 100kb.

I'm pretty sure it is a limit set on your site in IIS. Try those steps:

1. Open IIS Manager and select your site
2. Double click "Configuration Manager" (you can use filter to find it)
3. Select `system.webServer` and then `serverRuntime`
4. Modify `uploadReadAheadSize` (you might take a look at `maxRequestEntityAllowed` also which specifies the maximum number of bytes allowed in the request body)
5. Click `Apply`

[image]